# Cannot figure out how to install numpy with Python 3.3.3 and Windows 7 64bit

Tags: python, numpy, miniconda

This is driving me nuts.  I'm brand new to python and just want to be able to import numpy but have failed while trying to follow 20 different sets of instructions.  I know very little about installing things from command prompts, so please don't assume any knowledge.

So far I have installed pip and gotten that to seemingly work ok.  When running "pip install numpy" from the cmd prompt it seemed to download OK but have a ton of error messages, ending with "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy".  I hadn't installed a compiler or anything and read that may be the issue.  I installed mingw and selected most of the packages.  I also added the mingw\bin to my path variable.  Still nothing.

I THEN tried getting miniconda and using "conda install numpy python=3" because I read somewhere that that would work.  That seems to install successfully but then all the files are in some "miniconda" directory and when I try the "import numpy" command from my IDLE3 interpreter, it still says no module named numpy.

So what is next?  And why on earth is it so difficult to install and import a module?  One fact that may be complicating things:  I have my harddrive partitioned and I'm installing everything python related on drive G.  My path variable is updated to include the relevant G:\ directories.  My install log from pip:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
G:\Python333\Scripts\pip run on 01/25/14 09:24:37
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  URLs to search for versions for numpy:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/n/numpy/numpy-1.0.1.dev3460.win32-py2.4.exe#md5=a55b13b1f141de2aa965d5c5554c4ad8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.3.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=28ee6681b04beb5bfc4bc056417ff087 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.5-nosse.exe#md5=bfcb66706ebdece6a9680f79f2b643ca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=539782c7311d4a3379f66a964159ef11 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=33686581523c9e7368aefdd63a5952ef (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=196bac98eebdc953b135a12f0e379d11 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=05c06781b01326e60ba0921835c44fa0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=122d3fd5b78b7c36d4f57863391e2fb0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.0.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=95fd147bb761ca8e2baf34a153586358 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.6-nosse.exe#md5=267627e760277e5f6a74a83772a4f1d0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=e09cd07ba120ed9c84b85c7a188b3bce (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=67e0c10cf55b713bd27cbba94dee9673 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=941e4b1b65923addf8a7dc21ec7dbb7e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=69b04d57b3d18b266bcce6ecc52d1e06 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=1b6fd69c28336f399e803a145df29c3d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.7-nosse.exe#md5=7d6e48b35570c3d83db4cd0a4346b6c1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=6f5266d348e5f4d1471a6ae66c26438d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=30bec16292be262bd78ff1878a7d8953 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=3757650455a3cb50bf205bbc4c7f4703 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=7ad31a61947cb91915eb0bfdb01d2ab8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=dc11133ce1ce90ceb8f715e879a96e5f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py3.1-nosse.exe#md5=13c5ebdd920f2c756602358135fd7196 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=917c6b217b3867fe2cbdb788e4e6bb32 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=e2b539da620e186df211dbd7339a8993 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=0503aa98053340a1a86e0758648e5d75 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=7c4afe46ba670cae7e6fada849ffd464 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=5c9ebca6a0f513f1f1a34e150575d715 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=7863302af8928fb345c420c6af136197 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=a6b66602e72436db37e6edbbce269fdf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=b98cc04b20347127e297a99b6114b514 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=1b12834a53d3ba543d41399c40b5b791 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=651465cacf107d254ddcefcebb47064d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=4f20740e7e9d31a9d4c1636a931bc3f9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=6519c7bb198d0caf2913469883a63be9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.3.0.tar.gz#md5=3f7773ff0971a5ebb8591536d8ec7bd6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.3.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=89b8a56e018b634f7d05c56f17bc4943 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.4.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=3a8bfdc434df782d647161c48943ee09 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.5.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=376ef150df41b5353944ab742145352d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.tar.gz#md5=e0993c74cb8e83292e560eac1a9be8e9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.zip#md5=f0ce7ea1a12b3b3480571980af243e48 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.tar.gz#md5=2bce18c08fc4fce461656f0f4dd9103e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.zip#md5=462c22b8eb221c78ddd51de98fbb5979 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz#md5=95ed6c9dcc94af1fc1642ea2a33c1bba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.zip#md5=7e13c931985f90efcfa0408f845d6fee (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.tar.gz#md5=4fa54e40b6a243416f0248123b6ec332 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.zip#md5=ca27913c59393940e880fab420f985b4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=0ab72b3b83528a7ae79c6df9042d61c6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.zip#md5=9a72db3cad7a6286c0d22ee43ad9bc6c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.2.tar.gz#md5=6eba32e71bd30cf70b9ea2ef28519d9a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.2.zip#md5=b9d88d0a57166915cc2e2434466310b5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=2a4b0423a758706d592abb6721ec8dcd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.zip#md5=6c918bb91c0cfa055b16b13850cfcd6e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.0
  Using version 1.8.0 (newest of versions: 1.8.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.1, 1.3.0)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=2a4b0423a758706d592abb6721ec8dcd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/)
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running egg_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.3
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.3\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.3\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Running from numpy source directory.
    c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1522: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1531: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1534: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1428: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1439: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1442: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    G:\Python333\lib\distutils\dist.py:257: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

  libraries openblas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blas_info:

  libraries blas not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blas_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'

lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in G:\Python333\libs

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

  libraries lapack not found in ['G:\\Python333\\lib', 'C:\\', 'G:\\Python333\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



running egg_info

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build\src.win-amd64-3.3

creating build\src.win-amd64-3.3\numpy

creating build\src.win-amd64-3.3\numpy\distutils

building library "npymath" sources

No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Running from numpy source directory.

c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1522: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1531: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1534: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1428: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1439: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1442: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

G:\Python333\lib\distutils\dist.py:257: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python333\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "G:\Python333\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 274, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "G:\Python333\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1215, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "G:\Python333\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 321, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "G:\Python333\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\zak\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Zak\numpy
```

Comment: Installing compiled Python modules on windows is a pain. Best stick to a precompiled distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be easier to download prebuilt binary from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

If your python installation is 32-bit, then you are looking for `numpy-MKL-1.8.0.win32-py3.3.exe`. For 64-bit python: `numpy-MKL-1.8.0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe`.

---

Or you can install [`Anaconda`](http://continuum.io/downloads) python distribution, which includes all of common scientific packages: http://continuum.io/downloads and Ctrl+F for "Windows installers".

---

There are also thorough tutorials in SciPy documentation:

- [Building and installing NumPy (Windows)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html#windows)
- [Building From Source on Windows](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same horrible experience installing and spent over 8 hours trying to get a fix and finally got it solved.

Installing extension modules e.g. NumPy can be an issue with pip. In most cases the best way to install NumPy on your system is by using an installable binary package for your operating system and Python version from the [NumPy from Sourceforge download site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.1/)

For your Python 3.3. on Windos 7 (64 bits), the installation steps are:

1) download numpy installer: [numpy-1.8.1-win32-superpack-python3.3.exe (9.7 MB) for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.1/numpy-1.8.1-win32-superpack-python3.3.exe/download/)

2) run the .exe file and numpy will be installed into the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`(where all packages installed using 'pip install package_name' or 'python setup.py install' commands are stored)

3) In your home directory on the command prompt, type 'pip list' command to view installed packages, and you will see the numpy version you just installed (this step will only work if you have installed Python and pip package as well as added the directories for both installations to your PATH in environment variables)

Comment: Are you sure the link you have is for the 64 bits version? According to the other answer, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems with Python 3.5 and numpy 1.9.3 pip install finally works.

I have Win7(64bits) / Python 3.5(32bits) / Visual Studio 2015 Express:

- Open VS CMD tool
- Run pip install numpy

Answer (score 1):

In order to install additional Python packages without messing with existing Anaconda's configurations, I think,  now we can use `pip` from within IDLE, not like the friendly `pip install numpy`, but like so at two prompts successively:

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","numpy"])
```

However, just a heads-up: the installation process is not pretty, and slow. Similarly, if you have to install SciPy, just replace `numpy` with`scipy` in the above code.