# How can I access particular column values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
cname,query,status
a,aaa,c
a,aaa,c
a,aaa,c
a,aaa,p
a,aaa,a
b,bbb,c
b,bbb,c
b,bbb,a
b,bbb,a
b,bbb,c
```

This is my dataframe. I have to access status column and find how many c, p, a in status column based on `cname`.

I need output like following format

```
cname,query,c,p,a
a,5,3,1,1
b,5,3,0,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and then filter index by [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - remove last row:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='cname', 
                     columns='status', 
                     values='query',
                     aggfunc=len,
                     margins=True).fillna(0).astype(int)

print df1

status  a  c  p   All
cname                
a       1  3  1     5
b       2  3  0     5
All     3  6  1    10
```

Remove last row:

```
print df1[:-1]

status  a  c  p   All
cname                
a       1  3  1     5
b       2  3  0     5
```

Comment: TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'margins_name' this error is came

Comment: What version of pandas use? `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: pandas: 0.14.1 python version is 2.7

Comment: There is problem, the newest is version `0.18.0`. Is possible update version?

Comment: i m using anaconda spyder...is it possible to update pandas version?

Comment: Yes, it is easy. do you use windows or linux?

Comment: So open `cmd.exe` and write `conda install pandas`

Comment: ya...ok...nw i m trying to install

Comment: ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Comment: I think you can try `conda install numpy`, but it is interesting that pandas install script dont install numpy.

Comment: If write `print pd.show_versions()` is there module numpy? If yes, what is version of numpy? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352893/cannot-figure-out-how-to-install-numpy-with-python-3-3-3-and-windows-7-64bit?rq=1) and maybe the best solution is unninstall `anaconda`, delete directory where was anaconda installed, download [new version](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and install it. Sorry.

Comment: sorry now i m not able to import pandas.(import pnadas as pd)

Comment: k no prblm...nw i m trying to install new version...bt alexander code also woriking in older version(above answer)

Comment: Hmmm, I think if you remove `margins_name='qury'` it can works too. But I cannot verify it, because my version of `pandas` is `0.18.0`.

Comment: i think this question made our new friendship.

Comment: is it there any chat option in stackoverflow?

Comment: You can go [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108784/discussion-between-jezrael-and-sai-rajesh)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> (df.groupby(['cname', 'query'])
       .status
       .agg({'count': 'count'})
       .join(pd.concat([df[['cname']], pd.get_dummies(df.status)], axis=1)
       .groupby('cname')
       .sum()))

            count  a  c  p
cname query                
a     aaa       5  1  3  1
b     bbb       5  2  3  0
```

I am not sure how the `query` column relates to your requested grouping.  For example, how would the results look if the first row of `query` was 'aa' instead of 'aaa'? As a result, I grouped on the first two columns.

Comment: where 'a' is the cname and 'aaa' is the query

Comment: than you so much @Alexander...this code is working well.